# Execute QTP TestSet from REST

Tags: rest, qtp, hp-quality-center

Does anyone have an xml block that will kick off a testset (curl example would be great)?

The REST documentation in HP-ALM does not show how to execute a testset from REST.  There is a description of how to create a defect.  The secondary problem is that the docs suggest that required fields include cycle_id and testcycl_id for which I can't find a way to get their values.

Specifically - I want to create a Run object via POST

thanks

Answer (score 0):

ALM REST API Does not have the feature to kickoff Automated tests. We need to go with OTA API for the same.

Answer (score 0):

By OTA try this code in VBS.

```
    Set tdc = CreateObject("TDAPIOLE80.TDConnection")

    tdc.InitConnectionEx "https://URLALM"
    tdc.login "USer", "pass"
    tdc.Connect "DOMAIN", "PROJECT"

    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    'Set TSetFact = tdc.TestSetFactory
    Set tsTreeMgr = tdc.TestSetTreeManager
    Set tsFolder = tsTreeMgr.NodeByPath("your tree")
    Set tsList = tsFolder.FindTestSets("testSet")
    Set theTestSet = tsList.Item(1) 'list of testSets

    Set Scheduler = theTestSet.StartExecution("")

    if err.number <> 0 then
        'msgbox err.Description
    Else
        Scheduler.RunAllLocally = True
        Scheduler.Run

        Set execstatus = Scheduler.ExecutionStatus
        Do While RunFinished = False
            execstatus.RefreshExecStatusInfo "all", True
            RunFinished = execstatus.Finished
            Set EventsList = execstatus.EventsList
            For Each ExecEventInfoObj In EventsList
                strNowEvent = ExecEventInfoObj.EventType
            Next
            For i = 1 To execstatus.Count
                Set TestExecStatusobj = execstatus.Item(i)
                intTestid = TestExecStatusobj.TestInstance
            Next
        Loop

        execstatus.RefreshExecStatusInfo "all", True
    End if

    Set tsTreeMgr = nothing
    Set tsFolder = nothing
    Set tsList = nothing
    Set theTestSet =nothing

    tdc.Disconnect
    tdc.Logout

   tdc.ReleaseConnection
   Set tdc = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks, in my testing the vb object only works on desktop os or <Win2003 server, which is getting tough to find these days in a data center.

Answer (score 0):

Through Rest Api,You can create run for each of the test instance in a test set and update each of the step through run-steps of that particular test case while execution.
While creating the run you have update following mandatory field:-

```
http://<server>/qcbin//rest/domains/<>/projects/<>/runs/

<Entity Type=\"run\"><Fields>
<Field Name=\"name\"><Value>Run_2015-04-15</Value></Field>
<Field Name=\"testcycl-id\"><Value>573269</Value></Field>
<Field Name=\"cycle-id\"><Value>4363</Value></Field>
<Field Name=\"test-id\"><Value>29201</Value></Field>
<Field Name=\"subtype-id\"><Value>hp.qc.run.MANUAL</Value></Field>
<Field Name=\"owner\"><Value>owner</Value></Field>
</Fields></Entity>
```

After creating run ,you need to fetch Run-ID{Run ID} from the generated Response Xml
`/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/runs/?query={name[Run_2015-04-15]}`-use this url to get {Run ID} 
will be used to update steps.Used in following Url

```
/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/runs/{Run ID}/
```

For run-steps:-
To get the ID for the particular Step (like Step 1,2...).Use following query url.

```
/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/runs/{Run ID}/run-steps/?query={name[Step 1]}-use this url to get Step ID {ID}.
```

To Update Step:-
1. Use following url:-

```
 /qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/runs/{Run ID}/run-steps/{ID}
```

2.Generate the Xml and use post method to update status field.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <Entity Type="run-step">
+ <ChildrenCount>
  <Value>0</Value> 
  </ChildrenCount>
- <Fields>
+ <Field Name="test-id">
  <Value>6</Value> 
  </Field>
+ <Field Name="comp-status">
  <Value /> 
  </Field>
  <Field Name="rel-obj-id" /> 
  <Field Name="obj-id" /> 
+ <Field Name="has-linkage">
  <Value>N</Value> 
  </Field>
+ <Field Name="execution-date">
  <Value>2017-09-25</Value> 
  </Field>
+ <Field Name="path">
  <Value /> 
  </Field>
+ <Field Name="desstep-id">
  <Value>1031</Value> 
  </Field>
+ <Field Name="attachment">
  <Value>Y</Value> 
  </Field>
+ <Field Name="has-picture">
  <Value>N</Value> 
  </Field>
  <Field Name="tree-parent-id" /> 
+ <Field Name="id">
  <Value>24820</Value> 
  </Field>
+ <Field Name="component-data">
  <Value /> 
  </Field>
+ <Field Name="bpt-path">
  <Value /> 
  </Field>
+ <Field Name="actual">
  <Value><html><body> Results match expected </body></html></Value> 
  </Field>
+ <Field Name="step-order">
  <Value>1</Value> 
  </Field>
  <Field Name="level" /> 
+ <Field Name="expected">
  <Value><html><body> <div align="left"> <font face="Arial"><span style="font-size:8pt">Successful launch of website</span></font> </div> </body></html></Value> 
  </Field>
  <Field Name="line-no" /> 
+ <Field Name="comp-subtype-name">
  <Value /> 
  </Field>
- <Field Name="extended-reference">
  <Value /> 
  </Field>
- <Field Name="name">
  <Value>Step 1</Value> 
  </Field>
+ <Field Name="execution-time">
  <Value>03:56:29</Value> 
  </Field>
+ <Field Name="bpta-condition">
  <Value /> 
  </Field>
+ <Field Name="user-template-01">
  <Value>Website Tester</Value> 
  </Field>
+ <Field Name="parent-id">
  <Value>1522</Value> 
  </Field>
+ <Field Name="user-template-03">
  <Value /> 
  </Field>
+ <Field Name="bpt-facet-type">
  <Value /> 
  </Field>
+ <Field Name="user-template-04">
  <Value>kama</Value> 
  </Field>
- <Field Name="status">
  <Value>Passed</Value> 
  </Field>
  </Fields>
```